# UI for adding roles and modules to a user list

Tags: javascript, html, underscore.js, knockout.js

I have a small UI that involves adding roles and modules to a user database array.  The interface works as is, no problem at all, but it seems to have a bit of 'duplicate' code that I was hoping I could get some advice on ways to refactor, if at all possible.

JS and Knockout

```
function Db() {
    var self = this;

    self.userRoles = ['Executive', 'Admin', 'User'];
    self.userModules = ['Explore', 'Dashboards', 'Alerts'];
    self.userDatabases = ko.observableArray();
    self.allRolesSelected = ko.observableArray();
    self.allModulesSelected = ko.observableArray();

    self.databases = _.range(5).map(function (i) {
        return {
            name: 'DB ' + (i + 1),
            chosenRoles: ko.observableArray(),
            chosenModules: ko.observableArray()
        };
    });

    self.toggleAllRoles = function (r, e) {
        var checked = e.target.checked;

        if (checked) {
            self.setAllRoles(r);
        } else {
            self.clearAllRoles(r);
        }
    };
    self.toggleAllModules = function (r, e) {
        var checked = e.target.checked;

        if (checked) {
            self.setAllModules(r);
        } else {
            self.clearAllModules(r);
        }
    };

    self.setAllRoles = function (r) {
        _.each(self.userDatabases(), function (d) {
            if (d.chosenRoles.indexOf(r) === -1) {
                d.chosenRoles.push(r);
            }
        });
    };
    self.setAllModules = function (r) {
        _.each(self.userDatabases(), function (d) {
            if (d.chosenModules.indexOf(r) === -1) {
                d.chosenModules.push(r);
            }
        });
    };

    self.clearAllRoles = function (r) {
        _.each(self.userDatabases(), function (d) {
            d.chosenRoles.remove(r);
        });
    };
    self.clearAllModules = function (r) {
        _.each(self.userDatabases(), function (d) {
            d.chosenModules.remove(r);
        });
    };

    ko.computed(function () {
        _.each(self.userRoles, function (r) {
            var all = self.userDatabases().length > 0 && _.every(self.userDatabases(), function (d) {
                return d.chosenRoles.indexOf(r) > -1;
            });

            if (all) {
                if (self.allRolesSelected.indexOf(r) === -1) {
                    self.allRolesSelected.push(r);
                }
            } else {
                self.allRolesSelected.remove(r);
            }
        });

        _.each(self.userModules, function (r) {
            var all = self.userDatabases().length > 0 && _.every(self.userDatabases(), function (d) {
                return d.chosenModules.indexOf(r) > -1;
            });

            if (all) {
                if (self.allModulesSelected.indexOf(r) === -1) {
                    self.allModulesSelected.push(r);
                }
            } else {
                self.allModulesSelected.remove(r);
            }
        });
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new Db());
```

HTML

```
<h5>Add a Database</h5>
<table>
    <tr data-bind="foreach: databases">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { id: 'module-db-' + $index() }, checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.userDatabases" />
            <!-- ko text: name -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<h5>Add Roles</h5>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>DB Name</td>
        <!-- ko foreach: $root.userRoles -->
        <td class="text--center">
            <div class="one-whole" data-bind="text: $data"></div>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="event: { change: $root.toggleAllRoles }, checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.allRolesSelected" />
        </td>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
    <!-- ko foreach: userDatabases -->
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <!-- ko foreach: {data: $root.userRoles, as: 'r'} -->
        <td class="text--center">
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: r, checked: $parent.chosenRoles" />
        </td>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
</table>

<h5>Add Modules</h5>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>DB Name</td>
        <!-- ko foreach: $root.userModules -->
        <td class="text--center">
            <div class="one-whole" data-bind="text: $data"></div>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="event: { change: $root.toggleAllModules }, checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.allModulesSelected" />
        </td>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
    <!-- ko foreach: userDatabases -->
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <!-- ko foreach: {data: $root.userModules, as: 'm'} -->
        <td class="text--center">
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: m, checked: $parent.chosenModules" />
        </td>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
</table>
<br />
<br />
<!-- ko foreach: userDatabases -->
<strong data-bind="text: name" class="float--left clear"></strong>

<ul data-bind="foreach: chosenRoles" class="float--left">
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
<ul data-bind="foreach: chosenModules" class="float--left">
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few items that I could think of.  I know nothing about Knockout so if these changes do not work in that framework (I don't know why they wouldn't).

The first thing I would do is wrap the code with an IIFE to create a private scope.  Again, this might not be necessary with Knockout.

```
(function(){
  //your code here
})();
```

Next, you can DRY out your code quite a bit.  For example,  this:

```
self.toggleAllRoles = function (r, e) {
    var checked = e.target.checked;

    if (checked) {
        self.setAllRoles(r);
    } else {
        self.clearAllRoles(r);
    }
};
self.toggleAllModules = function (r, e) {
    var checked = e.target.checked;

    if (checked) {
        self.setAllModules(r);
    } else {
        self.clearAllModules(r);
    }
};
```

could be re-written as this just by passing one additional variable:

```
self.toggleAll = function ( r, e, roleOrModule ) { 
  // roleOrModule = 'role' or 'module' ( or anything not 'role' )
  self.setOrClear( r,  roleOrModule, e.target.checked );
};
```

You can do something similar with the `setAllRoles`, `setAllModules`, `clearAllRoles` and `clearAllModules` methods:

```
self.setOrClear = function( r, roleOrModule, pushOrRemove ) {
  var method = ( roleOrModule === 'role' ) ? 'chosenRoles' : 'chosenModule';
  var pushRemove = ( pushOrRemove ) ? 'push' : 'remove';
  _.each( self.userDatabases(), function (d) {
      if ( d[ method ].indexOf( r ) === -1) {
          d[ method ][ pushRemove ](r);
      }
  });
};
```

Lastly, I would again do this in the last section:

```
ko.computed(function () {
  var eachMethod = ['userRoles','userModules'];
  var chosenMethod = ['chosenRoles','chosenModules'];
  var allMethod = ['allRolesSelected', 'allModulesSelected'];

  for (var i=0, l = eachMethod.length; i < l; i++) {
    _.each(self[ eachMethod[i] ], function (r) {
        var all = self.userDatabases().length > 0 && _.every(self.userDatabases(), function (d) {
            return d[ chosenMethod[i] ].indexOf(r) > -1;
        });

        if (all) {
            if (self[ allMethod[i] ].indexOf(r) === -1) {
                self[ allMethod[i] ].push(r);
            }
        } else {
            self[ allMethod[i] ].remove(r);
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, I have no way to test this code.
I hope that helps!